# Firestack: firestack.auth.signInWithProvider('facebook', token, '') not firing

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I wouldn't consider myself a bad developer, but 2 days into trying to get facebook login working with react native and firebase is making me think otherwise!

I have started again from scratch and am trying to implement react-native-firestack. Unfortunately I have hit a road block just trying to get the package setup.

The firestack events seem to work fine (e.g. console.logs from firestack.auth.getCurrentUser() seem to work fine - in that they fire).

Unfortunately the signInWithProvider event doesn't seem to fire. the console.log()s just before it fire, with the correct data being passed. I am hoping I have just missed some little detail, I have tried to copy all the code directly from the relevant tutorials from react-native-firestack and react-native-facebook-login (the login one looks to be running well).

See below for my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {FBLogin, FBLoginManager} from 'react-native-facebook-login';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Firestack from 'react-native-firestack';
import FBLoginView from './src/FBLoginView';


export default class appTest extends Component {
  render() {
    const firestack = new Firestack();

    firestack.auth.listenForAuth((evt) => {
      if (!evt.authenticated) {
        // There was an error or there is no user
        console.log(evt.error);
      } else {
        // evt.user contains the user details
        console.log('User details', evt.user);
      }
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Listening for authentication changes'));

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <FBLogin
          buttonView={<FBLoginView />}
          ref={(fbLogin) => { this.fbLogin = fbLogin }}
          loginBehavior={FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Native}
          permissions={["email","user_friends"]}
          onLogin={function(data){
            console.log("Logged in!");
            let token = data.credentials.token;
            firestack.auth.signInWithProvider('facebook', token, '')
            .then((user) => {
              console.log(user)
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.error('User signin error', err);
            });
          }}
          onLoginFound={function(e){console.log(e)}}
          onLoginNotFound={function(e){console.log(e)}}
          onLogout={function(e){console.log(e)}}
          onCancel={function(e){console.log(e)}}
          onPermissionsMissing={function(e){console.log(e)}}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('appTest', () => appTest);
```

Comment: does this one fire?
console.log("Logged in!");

Comment: Yes, everything before the signInWithProvider run. I have also tried running console.log(token) after setting it and it works. The data is there - Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code at the moment.. just two things you could check: 

1) go to firebase and review if you have the sign-in method (facebook) enabled
2) is data.credentials.token a string?

Comment: Thanks, always good to sanity check those things - tried both of your suggestions without any luck unfortunately. I appreciate your help bouncing ideas though today